# IBM Worklight 6.2. Configure security roles per runtime environment (.war project)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

When you access to worklight console you have the list of runtime environments deployed (.war projects). Then you can enter to each environment and operate with the applications, adapters, analytics, etc.

Reading the documentation I found there are several roles you can configure to operate with the worklight console.

The question is if it is possible to configure those roles per runtime environment, or any other way to define different group of users that will have permission to access to each runtime environment.

If it is not, would it be supported to install more than one Worklight console in the same WAS server? This way we could define different roles for each console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the question about deploying several Worklight consoles in the same WAS server, the response is yes. You have to use of course different context roots for the different Worklight consoles/Worklight admin services and specify a different value for the JNDI property ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid. The Worklight runtime must have the same ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid that the one used for the console that handles this runtime.

Comment: Is it a supported configuration?

Comment: Yes it is a supported configuration. You can have several Worklight consoles in the same JVM. It is why there is this ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid JNDI property that has no other role than to handle the different consoles and the runtimes managed by each console.

Answer (score 0):

There is no differentiation between runtimes (in either Worklight Foundation 6.2 or MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3).

After logging-in (to the Management console), the role the user is applied with will be the one used for any interaction with any runtime.

You may submit an enhancement request:  https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help/